# Criteria API filter by properties of different children

Tags: java, criteria-api

What is the better approach to get a Parent with at least one Sub with the name 'A' and at least one Sub with the name 'B' at the same time?

I have to use Criteria API to solve the problem.

I have such kind of entities with Many-To-Many relationship (some code omitted):

```
class Parent {
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Sub> Subs

}
```

```
class Sub {
    Long id

    String name;

    @ManyToMany
    List<Parent> Parents
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two inner joins as filters, so as not to have to implement a complex where clause as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Parent> cq = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);

Root<Parent> parent = cq.from(Parent.class);
Join<Parent,Sub> joinA = parent.join(parent.get("subs"),JoinType.INNER);
joinA.on(cb.equals(joinA.get("name"),"A"));

Join<Parent,Sub> joinB = parent.join(parent.get("subs"),JoinType.INNER);
joinB.on(cb.equals(joinB.get("name"),"B"));

cq.distinct(true);
cq.select(parent);

List<Parent> result = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

If you use a version of JPA prior to 2.1, you will not be able to use the ON clause in the JOINs so you will have to implement the predicates in the where like this (its and example):

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
predicates.add(cb.equals(joinA.get("name"),"A"));
predicates.add(cb.equals(joinB.get("name"),"B"));
cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```